# Change password ticket error Auth0

Tags: api, auth0

I am having problem using the Change password ticket feature through the API using Auth0.

Something with connection_id ? If it isn't the name of my db, where do I find it? ?

error message:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Payload validation error: 'String does not match pattern ^con_[A-Za-z0-9]{16}$: Health-Users' on property connection_id (The connection that provides the identity for which the password is to be changed. If sending this parameter, the email is also required and the user_id is invalid).",
  "errorCode": "invalid_body"
}
```

When adding user_id param I get this error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Payload validation error: 'Invalid property user_id'.",
  "errorCode": "invalid_body"
}
```

I have tried both through the API directly and with Postman, and both give same error.

Comment: can you show us the body you are using to call  the ticket API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API endpoint you're trying to use needs the connection's ID, which is different from the connection name. You can get a connection's ID through the management API's Connections endpoints.

Comment: FYI if you don't want to use the management API I was able to look through the network requests tab when using the Auth0 web console and find it pretty easily.